# How do I add a notification for process completions

Tags: 10.04, notification, tools

How can I add a notification of some sort (like playing a .wav file or creating a pop-up on the status bar) when a process finishes. 
For example, I am compiling a program that takes a couple of hours to finish. I would like to hear/see some sort of message when it completes compiling. Is there a tool for doing this (like tying an `alarm` program to the `pid` of a process) or something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Desktop notification when long running commands complete](http://askubuntu.com/questions/409611/desktop-notification-when-long-running-commands-complete)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to get a popup (a desktop notification) is to install the libnotify-bin package, then add "alert" to your command line, like this:

```
./configure && make && alert
```

Note that "alert" is a convenience alias, if you type:

```
alias alert
```

you will see that behind the scenes it calls the `notify-send` command, which has a bunch of interesting options, so you may want to define your own alias to call `notify-send` in a way that better suits you.

Comment: I would suggest running something like `make && notify-send "make" "done" || notify-send "make" "an error occured"`. To send a message even if make fails.