# How to get a process exit status from another shell session?

Tags: command-line, scripts, process

Suppose I run a command in one shell session, for example `bash -c 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade'`. 5 minutes later I decide to go outside for a snack, and realize I forgot to [add some form of notification mechanism](https://askubuntu.com/q/409611/295286) for whether exit was success or failure.

Well, what do  I now ? If only I could query from another terminal the exit status of that other command ( or specifically, that PID), maybe I could after all display some sort of pop up. So the question is: how can I query exit status of an already running process from another terminal ?

In other words,

> GIVEN that I have a running process in terminal A  AND its PID is known
>
> WHEN I execute some command in terminal B
>
> THEN I should be able to know if process in terminal A finishes with exit status 0 or exit status >1.

Comment: So you want something (an alert command reporting the exit code?) to run once a specified, arbitrary process A (given PID) terminates, after attaching a "watcher" to it with command B? We can not assume that A is a background job running in the same shell where you later type B, no?

Comment: @ByteCommander Correct.  It's a foreground job.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get a return code from a child of a different shell. You can use `wait` to get the code of a background process in your current shell, after it terminates, but I could not find anything that would allow querying other shells. Simply monitoring whether a process is still running and raising an alert once it exits is also trivial again, but not finding out its exit code. The only way I could possibly think of would require preparing your shell's `PROMPT_COMMAND` to store the last exit code in a tempfile or similar accessible location. Would that be an option?

Comment: @ByteCommander Nope. No preparing terminal A, do everything from terminal B.  And trust me, it's possible.

Comment: Well, it would be a permanent preparation (editing .bashrc once), but okay. Looking forward to read the answer, if you find one.

Comment: @ByteCommander I already do, I just wanna see what others come up with. :)

Comment: @dsstorefile1 I'm not familiar with what TIOCSTI is or with ioctl() syscall, so maybe ?

Comment: I know you already have an answer but want some comments first....Um go to Terminal A and type `echo $?`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix hehe,  would give exit status from within terminal A. I want it from within terminal B.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `strace` as follows:

```bsh
sudo strace -e trace=none -e signal=none -q -p $PID
```

Neither system calls nor signals are of interest here, so we tell `strace` to ignore them with the `-e` expressions and supress a status message with `-q`. `strace` attaches to the process with PID `$PID`, waits for it to exit normally and outputs its exit status like this:

```bsh
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

A simple `if` expression to call any type of notification could be:

```bsh
if sudo strace -e trace=none -e signal=none -q -p $PID |& grep -q ' 0 '; then
  echo yeah
else
  echo nope
fi
```

#### Example run

```bsh
# in terminal 1
$ (echo $BASHPID;sleep 10;true)
8807
# in terminal 2
$ if sudo strace -e{trace,signal}=none -qp8807|&grep -q ' 0 ';then echo yeah;else echo nope;fi
yeah

# in terminal 1
$ (echo $BASHPID;sleep 10;false)
12285
# in terminal 2
$ if sudo strace -e{trace,signal}=none -qp12285|&grep -q ' 0 ';then echo yeah;else echo nope;fi
nope
```

Most of the credit goes to [this answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86860/246819), please leave an upvote there if you find this useful.