# How do I tell if a command is running or waiting for user input?

Tags: command-line, process, io

On command line, I typed a command and hit enter. It doesn't output anything . How do I tell if it's running and not yet output, or it's asking for user input?

Comment: If it is waiting then you will not get `PS1` prompt.

Comment: 1. Please tell us which program it is (that is silent), and we can give you more precise advice about what to expect and how to check it; 2. Would you like to get an alert, when the program finally asks for input or has finished (so that something is written to the terminal window?

Comment: if there is an input expected I would assume you get a prompt with a message in front of it asking for input.

Comment: @Rinzwind - That is a poor assumption. First counterexample to mind is the `cat` command. Just type `cat` by itself and it will wait for input from stdin, but gives no prompt. _Many_ other commands behave similarly because they expect input from either stdin or a file, but don't differentiate between different input sources (interactive terminal, pipe, file...).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's several approaches:

1. **Try signalling end of input**:Without superuser privileges it is hard to know what is going on underneath the hood. What can be done is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. Terminals and utilities in [canonical mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/358381/3701431) send all available text to `read()` syscall upon receiving EOT signal bound to this key combination, and if there's no input - `read()` returns negative exit status which most utilities accept as signal to exit. Therefore, if a utility is waiting for input it will exit upon receiving the key combination. Otherwise, the utility is either running tasks or is not written properly.
2. **Spying on syscalls**:If you do have superuser privilege, you can run `strace` in another terminal to see what is currently being done. For that you need to find out PID of the program. For instance, in another terminal tab run `pgrep -f firefox` which may 1234 as example and then `sudo strace -f -p 1234`. If the output you see is stuck on `read()` syscall, it means the command probably is waiting for input. Otherwise, if you see syscalls running by, then command is doing something else. See a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071821/how-to-get-a-process-exit-status-from-another-shell-session) for usage of `strace` to also figure out if the long running command has exited.
3. **Use command's own methods**: Among other things, such utilities as `dd` use signals. For instance, if you use `kill -USR1 1234` (where 1234 is PID of the running `dd` command), it will print to stdout the amount of bytes currently processed. Of course, this requires knowing about such behavior of the command in the first place. The above two methods are more general, and don't require deep knowledge of each command's behavior ( though it's always best to know what you're actually executing - otherwise you risk running a command which may do damage ).

Comment: +1. Thanks for the `strace` method :-) But simpler methods are also useful (general or specific for each program). Some of them work without superuser privileges. Examples: check if `dd` is doing something and check why `grep --color asdf` is waiting silently.

Comment: @sudodus Ah, good reminder about `dd` I'll add that one.

Comment: You don't need superuser privileges to debug a process owned by your user. Well, unless you haven't [set the system up appropriately](https://askubuntu.com/a/41656/113421).

Comment: does the ubuntu terminal execution pause when some other window is clicked and becomes the new active window?

Comment: @Shyam No, execution does not pause. If you experience such event something else is affecting your GUI. I'd suggest posting a question with exact details of your situation and someone may answer it in more details

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, later I found that the execution dint pause. But the execution just was at the same position for a long time, so I got slightly confused as to what was going on. But many a times previously I had experienced situations like when I select a portion of text on my terminal app in ubuntu. Then copy the text, the execution stops for a while. Then if I paste somewhere else and comeback and select this terminal app and only after I press ctrl+c, the further text appears outputted on the app.

Answer (score 6):

## How to tell if a program is running or wanting user input

It depends on the program and how you invoke it.

- Often but not always there will be a prompt, that indicates that the program is asking for input.
- If you are not sure, you can check if the program's process is busy

  - uses CPU - use **`top`** or **`htop`**
  - reads or writes - use **`sudo iotop -o`**
- And when the program has finished, you will see the shell's prompt.

## Shellscript `running`

I had a shellscript that checks if a program is running, and now I have added the option `-s` to make it run `sudo strace -f -p <PID>` (according to Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's answer) when a ...  is found.

The shellscript uses

- `ps -ef` to find the majority of programs
- `systemctl is-active --quiet` to find some programs
- and if you wish `strace` in an `xterm` window.

  Install `xterm` if you want to use `strace` to watch the activity of a program.

#### Usage

```
$ ./running
Usage:    ./running <program-name>
          ./running <part of program name>
Examples: ./running firefox
          ./running term                     # part of program name
          ./running dbus
          ./running 'dbus-daemon --session'  # words with quotes
          ./running -v term                  # verbose output
          ./running -s term                  # strace checks activity
```

You can install the shellscript `running` into a directory in `PATH` if you want easy access to it.

#### The shellscript code

```
#!/bin/bash

# date        sign     comment
# 2019-02-14  sudodus  version 1.0

verbose=false
strace=false
if [ "$1" == "-v" ]
then
 verbose=true
 shift
fi
if [ "$1" == "-s" ]
then
 strace=true
 shift
fi

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
 echo "Usage:    $0 <program-name>
          $0 <part of program name>
Examples: $0 firefox
          $0 term                     # part of program name
          $0 dbus
          $0 'dbus-daemon --session'  # words with quotes
          $0 -v term                  # verbose output
          $0 -s term                  # strace checks activity"
 exit
fi

inversvid="\0033[7m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"
redback="\0033[1;37;41m"
greenback="\0033[1;37;42m"
blueback="\0033[1;37;44m"

runn=false
#tmpfil=$(mktemp)
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
tmpfil="$tmpdir/tmpfil"
vtfile="$tmpdir/vtfile"
vthead="$tmpdir/vthead"

# check by systemctl

systemctl is-active --quiet "$1"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
 echo "systemctl is-active:"
 runn=true
fi

# check by ps

ps -ef | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 8- | grep "$1" | grep -vE -e "$0 *$1" -e "$0 *.* *$1" -e "grep $1" | sort -u > "$tmpfil"
#cat "$tmpfil"
if $verbose || $strace
then
 ps -ef |head -n1 > "$vthead"
 ps -ef | grep "$1" | grep -vE -e "$0 *.* *$1" -e "grep $1" | sort -u > "$vtfile"
fi

tmpstr=$(head -n1 "$tmpfil")
#echo "tmpstr=$tmpstr"
tmpess=$(grep -om1 "$1" "$tmpfil")
#echo "tmpess=$tmpess"
if [ "$tmpstr" == "$1" ] || [ "${tmpstr##*/}" == "$1" ] || [ "${1##*/}" == "${0##*/}" ] || [ "$tmpess" == "$1" ]
then
 echo "ps -ef: active:"
 runn=true
 if $verbose
 then
  cat "$vthead" "$vtfile"
 fi
elif test -s "$tmpfil"
then
 if $runn
 then
  echo "----- consider also ------------------------------------------------------------"
  if $verbose
  then
   cat "$vthead" "$vtfile"
  else
   cat "$tmpfil"
  fi
  echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
 else
  echo "----- try with: ----------------------------------------------------------------"
  if $verbose
  then
   cat "$vthead" "$vtfile"
  else
   cat "$tmpfil"
  fi
  echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
 fi
fi

if $runn
then
 echo -en "$greenback '$1"
 if [ "$tmpstr" != "$tmpess" ]
 then
  echo -n " ..."
 fi
 echo -e "' is running $resetvid"

 if $strace
 then
  which xterm
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
   pid=$(head -n1 "$vtfile" | sed 's/^ *//' | tr -s ' ' '\t' | cut -f 2)
   echo "checking pid=$pid; quit with 'ctrl + c' in the xterm window"
   xterm -title "'strace' checks '$1'" 2> /dev/null -e sudo strace -f -p $pid
  else
   echo "Please install 'xterm' for this function to work"
   exit
  fi
 fi
else
 inpath=$(which "$1")
 if [ "$inpath" == "" ]
 then
  echo -e "$redback no path found to '$1' $resetvid"
 else
  echo -e "$blueback '$1' is not running $resetvid"
 fi
fi
rm -r "$tmpdir"
```

#### Demo

Checking terminal windows in Lubuntu (LXTerminal started as `x-terminal-emulator` and custom `gnome-terminal` windows),

```
$ running -v -s term 
----- try with: ----------------------------------------------------------------
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
sudodus   2087  1384  0 13:33 ?        00:00:00 x-terminal-emulator
sudodus   2108  1269  0 13:33 ?        00:00:17 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 no path found to 'term' 

$ running -v -s x-terminal-emulator
ps -ef: active:
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
sudodus   2087  1384  0 13:33 ?        00:00:00 x-terminal-emulator
 'x-terminal-emulator' is running 
/usr/bin/xterm
checking pid=2087; quit with 'ctrl + c' in the xterm window
```

There is *a lot* of activity as soon as the cursor is in the terminal window.

[image]

Starting `grep` (waiting for input from `/dev/stdin`)

```
$ grep -i --color 'hello'
asdf
Hello World    
Hello World
```

Checking it

```
$ running -s grep
ps -ef: active:
 'grep ...' is running 
/usr/bin/xterm
checking pid=14982; quit with 'ctrl + c' in the xterm window
```

There is not much activity, and you can identify what is happening.

[image]

Comment: Good mention of `iotop`, though CPU usage might not necessarily be an indicator if a process is busy. A program written in C and optimized  might be using minimal CPU. Some of the indicators I've written in Python schedule a repeated task to run, so it might use CPU to update the indicator menu for a brief moment and then just sits there.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, Yes, you are right about that. The `strace` method is better, but maybe not necessary or not available.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think it comes preinstalled with Ubuntu, and might be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running the shell in a terminal, for example a terminal emulator or a typical ssh session, your shell has almost certainly enabled job control. This makes getting an answer to your question super easy in most cases.

Type <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> to suspend the process and then `bg` to continue it in the background, then type an empty line to the shell so it'll check whether the program got stopped by a signal.

If the process is trying to read from the terminal, it will immediately get a `SIGTTIN` signal and will get suspended. (When job control is enabled, the system allows only one process at a time to read from the terminal.) The shell will report this. You can then type `fg` to continue the process in the foreground, and then type input to be read by the program as normal.

```
mp@ubuntu:~$ sleep 30 # a program that is not reading from the terminal
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 30
mp@ubuntu:~$ bg
[1]+ sleep 30 &
mp@ubuntu:~$ 
mp@ubuntu:~$
```

```
mp@ubuntu:~$ cat - # a program that is reading from the terminal
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 cat -
mp@ubuntu:~$ bg
[1]+ cat - &
mp@ubuntu:~$ 
[1]+  Stopped                 cat -
mp@ubuntu:~$ jobs -l
[1]+  3503 Stopped (tty input)     cat -
mp@ubuntu:~$ fg
cat -
hi
hi
```

Some programs, such as editors, will either trap or ignore the signal generated by <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> or put the terminal into a mode where control characters don't even generate signals. You'll need to use more advanced techniques in this case, such as using `strace` to see if the process is doing `read`, `select`, `poll`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need this, but still a useful trick to know: if the program seems to exit without any output you can check if it is running in background by executing

```
ps -efa | grep "program_name"
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply look at the column S (State) of the top command. If your program is waiting for input, there is a great chance it is sleeping and not running meaning top will output a S (for Sleeping this time) and not a R (for Running). Try this command as an example:

`top -b -n 1 | sed -n '7,12p' | awk '{printf "%6s %-10s %-4s %-s\n",$1,$2,$8,$NF}'`