# display some text at the end of a script

Tags: bash, scripts, text

At the end of my scripts I use often put "konsole" bash command, to know that the script is completed.
Now I'd like to add a text within the konsole (terminal), something such as "done!".
How should I do? What bash command I should add to my scripts?
I tried with `konsole echo "done!"`, but usuccessfully.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you running your script by double mouse click within the file explorer and you want to keep the terminal window (where the script is executed) open after the script is finish?

Comment: No, I start the script usually via KDE menu (without terminal). Terminal appears only at last. But I think that my solution below is better. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's better something like this (with zenity):

```
zenity --info \
--text="<span size=\"xx-large\">done!</span>" \
--title="you did it!" \
--display=:0.0
```

at the end of the script

Comment: Or this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/656603/alert-when-terminal-program-finishes-running and https://askubuntu.com/questions/409611/desktop-notification-when-long-running-commands-complete

Answer (score 1):

Given you have accepted zenity pop-up as a solution, a similar result is possible with just:

`notify-send "you did it!"`